# Which is greater "Temptation or the action"?

Tags: matthew

Gospel according to Matthew (5:28-) Jesus "if you look a woman with a lustful eyes you have commited adultery with her". So my question is suppose a "person commited physical relationship outside marriage"  Which one is greater thought (temptation) or the action).

Need clearification please...

Comment: They are equal. The question should be which is first. Clearly the thought. You cannot commit an act without first thinking about it. Jesus was merely pointing out that just because you do not follow through on all your sinful desires, because sometimes you haven’t the opportunity to enact them, it still gets counted as sin because you didn’t stop yourself and saw nothing wrong with committing sin in your mind’s eye. You are therefore a sinner at heart and your inclination is towards sin. You merely have some physical restraints or laws preventing you but otherwise you would revel in it.

Comment: thats what Jesus said but you have added to the text and changed it to temptation. That’s not what Jesus is talking about. He said if you look at a women to lust after her. Not if you see an attractive woman and you are tempted to lust after her but deny yourself.

Comment: Thought and temptation are not the same thing.   The thrust of Matthew 5:28 and other passages from the Sermon on the Mount was that thoughts can in and of themselves be sinful, even if one does not act out physically.  One can be tempted to accept a sinful thought, but one does not have to accept that thought.

Comment: This may be clearer to understand when you compare hate versus murder.  Both are sin, but action is more damaging to the other person.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extremely delicate matter only because it is so close to everyone's inner being.  That is, we all have our pet sins that we hope no one will ever discover and we even try to fool ourselves about.  So let me define some terms and clarify some matters to better discuss this.

Temptations come from two sources - "external" and "internal" sources.  This is a matter of everyday experience.

**External Temptations** are those that come from outside ourselves such as a suggestion from an acquaintance or the way circumstances may occur.  In any case, we have little or no control over the manner or frequency of such temptations; the existence of such temptations, precisely because they are beyond our control, is not sinful.  I believe this is what Heb 4:15 is discussing.  Jesus was tempted but remained sinless.

**Internal Temptations** are those that arise from our own thoughts, often but not always, without any external stimulation.  Such a situation evidently arose in the case of Ananias and Sapphira (Acts 5:4) as Peter had to ask in astonishment, "*How have you thought up this deed in your heart?*"  Now, this is the very delicate part - because we are sinful humans, such ideas will necessarily crop up from time to time.  When does, it becomes a sin only of it finds fertile soild in lustful desire as per Jesus' comment in Matt 5:28?  [Note that God does have this problem since He is sinless - see Jer 7:31, 19:5, 32:35, James 1:13]

James :14, 15 provides some help:

> But each one is tempted when he is carried away and enticed by his own
>   lust. Then when lust has conceived, it gives birth to sin; and when
>   sin is accomplished, it brings forth death.

As I understand this verse, temptation must take root in the mind in order to produce desire.  Jesus' comment in Matt 5:28 specifically says that it requires temptation with lustful desire.  The implication is that temptation without lustful desire in not sinful.  Let me illustrate:  While I am as sinful as the next person, there are some temptations that do not affect me at all and others that do.  Which is which I am embarrassed to document except to say that the next person will have a different set.  We all have our pet sins.

Thus, temptation only becomes sin when it find fertile soil in the mind and brings forth lustful desire, whether money, sex, position, power, or whatever.

One last point: As far as God is concerned, all sin is sin for which Christ died.  However, not all sins are equal in their effects.  A person who works for years with a difficult colleague and constantly cherishes the idea of revenge by violence (or anything else) is as sinful as if the revenge were carried out (Matt 5:28).  However, the difficult person will be very glad if the idea only remains a lustful thought and is never physically executed.

Answer (score 0):

One must distinguish between temptation and agreement or consent to that temptation; the temptation isn't a sin, only indulgence in the sinful behavior (though, word, deed) suggested by the temptation.

> **Hebrews 4:15 (DRB)** For we have not a high priest, who can not have compassion on our infirmities: but **one tempted** in all things like as we are, **without sin.**

Deliberating over whether to sin or not is sinful in itself, since it presumes on God's mercy among other things (Cf. Sirach 5:8-10; Luke 12:19-20; Hebrews 12:16-17), but even intending to, e.g., commit adultery, is equivalent to having committed adultery ("has already committed adultery") in the sense that the same sin has been committed. This is because, between a case of someone who intends to or would commit adultery if not hindered by external factors (the law, image, etc.), and the case of someone who carries through with the deed, **the sinful intention is exactly the same** (namely indulging in lustful activity), and the offense to God already present—only **external** matters, external to the mind are different; namely, the position of physical matter—the bodies and organs thereof of the parties involved.

This is related to Jesus' more general teaching that all sin actually occurs in the heart, and the acts and externals being mere consequences of that (i.e. the 'deed' here with adultery).

> **Mark 7:21-22 (DRB)** For from within out of the heart of men proceed evil thoughts, adulteries, fornications, murders, 22 Thefts, covetousness, wickedness, deceit, lasciviousness, an evil eye, blasphemy, pride, foolishness. 23 All these evil things come from within, and defile a man.

Put another way, only willing the evil is the sinful part of a committed sin; and so someone who is raped, for example, is not the same as someone willingly engaging in illicit intercourse, even if the sexual union might be the same physically: the difference is in the heart and attitude toward the thing, and only ever was.

More striking is Jesus' teaching that if you hate your fellow man, you have committed murder! This gets at the heart of the teaching, and comes close to a 'hard saying' (John 6:60)

> **Matthew 5:22 (DRB)** But I say to you, that whosoever is angry with his brother, shall be in danger of the judgment. And whosoever shall say to his brother, Raca, shall be in danger of the council. And whosoever shall say, Thou Fool, shall be in danger of hell fire.

Cf. 1 John 3:15.

Along with the New Testament recognition and teaching that it is impossible to fulfill the moral law perfectly (swearing once already has ruptured friendship with God in an irreparable way—that is, reparation is only by the mercy of God and nothing else at all), come some of the reasons this is so: the perfection of morality according to a sober and mature understanding of it as known and here taught by God Himself and how He sees it, which is naturally fiercely unforgiving.

Hatred of your brother is equivalent, to God, to murder of your brother, because again you are only hindered by the law, by inconvenience, by consequences, otherwise, whether you know it or not—God knows it—you would have his right to exist taken away, as it were, no matter how fleeting the thought is. To use an analogy, think of a young person saying in a fit of rage, "I wish you were dead!" (to a parent, for example). That's hatred, and only falls short of murder in that you are hindered only by the inconvenience and personal remorse afterwards, thus revealing the gruesome nature of hatred and sin in general—you've committed adultery, murder, theft, in more ways than you can imagine. Blood, prison, anguish, regret are all consequences of something that has already been born in the heart.